# SQLite updation upon android app's update

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an app released on the android market which uses sqlite and displays data. I want to know if I am sending an update for the app by adding features, should I upload a new database? What happens when users already having my app, click on update? Will the database update on its own? If the users are downloading my app for the first time, they will certainly get the new db content...but what about the existing users?? I want to know if I have to explicitly update the database in the program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create your new version... If you change the version of the database... The onUpgrade function will run on all the existing users:

```
public static final int dbVersion = 2;
protected static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper { 
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, dbName, null, dbVersion);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //create tables
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        //what do you want to do to existing users? maybe recreate?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not create the sqlite database through code? That way your updates can update the SQL on the database (alter columns, add rows) without affecting the users existing data.

Comment: I have placed my current db in Assets folder and am retrieving it from there. SO I want to know if i need to replace the existing db or when the user select update...it will somehow fetch it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing database's attributes then on updation it will create problem and if the database's attributes are same then it will not have any effect...

Answer (score 0):

You may use `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper` class it supports versions and migration mechanism